# Como excluir páginas wordpress direto no banco de dados?

Tags: wordpress

Estou fazendo um clone de um site wordpress pra modelar e gerar outro site.

Porém, o site tem mais de 2500 páginas e preciso deixar apenas umas 10 que vou usar.

Como posso excluir as páginas diretamente no banco de dados sem precisar excluir de 20 em 20 como o wordpress permite?

Comment: Vc tem acesso ao BD: host, username e password?

Comment: @dvd tenho acesso sim

Answer (score 0):

A tabela onde se encontram as páginas, é a mesma onde estão os posts tabela `posts` ou `wp_posts` dependendo da sua configuração.

Pra excluir, basta utilizar o comando `delete from wp_posts where post_title like '%MEU_FILTRO%'` ou outro comando semelhante.